# Young Adult Sci-fi trilogy about a world where people can upload their minds but if they die in the simulation they'll die in the real world

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dystopia, mind-uploading

I read this book in 2018/2019. It's a young adult science fiction trilogy about a world where people can upload their minds and consciousness to a simulated computer world and interact with others. If they die in the computer world, they die in the real world too. If their body dies in the real world, however, they can still live in the computer world but they can't go back to the real world. People who upload their minds can technically live forever in the simulation.

Details about the story:

- The world is divided into two, the App World and the Real World. Most people can afford to upload their consciousness to the App World, but those who can't live in the Real World. Some of them are Keepers, or people who take care of the bodies in the plugs, a pod-like place where the bodies are kept.
- People in the App World are supposed to do the Service when they turn 17. The Service is when people unplug and experience the Real World for a year. The protagonist, Skye, has dreamed of doing the Service to reunite with her mother and sister, but then just before she did, the borders between worlds are closed and no one can unplug or plug in.
- She lives in her best friend's house.
- She gets a message after the borders are closed to come to a place where she could unplug.
- When Skye unplugs, her body is on display. She escapes and jumps off a cliff as many people watch.

Other details about the book:

- The author is American
- One the covers of the books in the trilogy is a girl in a long white dress floating horizontally. The tone of the cover is white to light blue/light green.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nevermind guys I found it lol. the series is called [unplugged](https://www.harpercollins.com/products/unplugged-donna-freitas) by [Donna Freitas](https://www.donnafreitas.com/about/). it was published from 2016-2017. thank you so much for reading my question

Comment: Sounds like and interesting read!

Comment: Can you add some more details about the book and how it matches? This site is searchable, and uses the text of questions and answers to try to predict matches. The more data you can provide, the more help this will be to future querents. Secondly, don't forget to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. As a self-answer, you have to wait 48 hours after the asking, but if you try early, it will just let you know how much time you have left.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan thanks!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots sure! i'll add them to my question.